# How to initialize an unorderd_set using C++ (g++ compiler)?

Tags: c++, initialization, unordered-set

I observe the following error while trying to compile a sample code with g++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>

int main () {
   std::unordered_set<std::string> second ( {"red","green","blue"} );    // init list
   std::unordered_set<std::string> second1 {"red", "green", "blue"}; // Marcelo Cantos
   std::unordered_set<std::string> second2{{"red", "green", "blue"}}; // Marcelo Cantos
   std::unordered_set<std::string> second3 = {"red", "green", "blue"};// Marcelo Cantos   
   return 0;

}

$ gcc -o wp -Wall -Wextra test_set.cpp 
test_set.cpp:5:45: error: expected expression
   std::unordered_set<std::string> second ( {"red","green","blue"} )...
                                        ^
test_set.cpp:6:43: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
   std::unordered_set<std::string> second1 {"red", "green", "blue"};
                                          ^
                                          ;
test_set.cpp:7:43: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
   std::unordered_set<std::string> second2{{"red", "green", "blue"}};
                                          ^
                                          ;
test_set.cpp:8:36: error: non-aggregate type 'std::unordered_set<std::string>' cannot be initialized with an initializer list
   std::unordered_set<std::string> second3 = {"red", "green", "blue"};
                                   ^         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
4 errors generated.


$ g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

Solved by using compiler option "-std=c++11".

$ g++ -o test_set -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 test_set.cpp

Comment: You should probably compile for [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) i.e. with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 test_set.cpp -o wp`

Comment: `#include <string>`.

Comment: -std=c++11 worked! Thanks, Basile. that was quick!

Comment: Please do not edit your question and add "[Solved]". It invalidates the purpose of Stack Overflow as a "Q&A" site. Add your answer as an *answer*; you can even 'accept' it yourself.

Comment: Thanks Jongware. I have fixed this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by using compiler option "-std=c++11".

```
$ g++ -o test_set -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 test_set.cpp
```

Answer (score 1):

Works for me.

```
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.51) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

You could try one of the following alternative forms, all of which work with clang 6.0:

```
…second{"red", "green", "blue"};
…second{{"red", "green", "blue"}};
…second = {"red", "green", "blue"};
```

Comment: All of the the above only work when -std=c++11 is used at compile time.
Editing with error message for each case.

Comment: @Rock: Ah yes. I'm so used to working in C++11 now, it didn't occur to me to ask.